Yarn shell does not support user's home directory (tilde ~)
Modern Yarn portable shell seems to not have implemented user's home directory (~) so commands like echo ~/.foo would fail. Instead of explicity calling shell, is there any equivalent to this symbol?

The environment variable $HOME can be used instead.
